# Oracle output parameter returns null

Tags: c#, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to get output values from database. Ween I debug in database side it seems it is printing correct values. But when I fetch same data from C# side, I get null values.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetAssetInfoSelect
(inTransactionID in varchar2,
varProcessorAction out varchar2,
varTransactionStatus out varchar2)
is

begin
 if (inTransactionID is not null) then
  select ProcessorAction, TransactionStatus into varProcessorAction, varTransactionStatus
    from tblAssetIDTransactions
    where TransactionID = inTransactionID;

end if;

END GetAssetInfoSelect;
```

[image]

```
private static bool GetAssetInfoSelect(string strTransactionID)
{
        try
        {
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstring);
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "GetAssetInfoSelect";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("inTransactionID", OracleType.Char)).Value = strTransactionID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("varProcessorAction", OracleType.Char,200)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("varTransactionStatus", OracleType.Char,200)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Debug.WriteLine(cmd.Parameters["varProcessorAction"].Value);
            Debug.WriteLine(cmd.Parameters["varTransactionStatus"].Value);
            //immitate if (inTransactionID is not null AND varProcessorAction = 'A' AND varTransactionStatus = 'A') then
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strTransactionID) && cmd.Parameters["varProcessorAction"].Equals('A') && cmd.Parameters["varTransactionStatus"].Equals('A'))
            {
                conn.Close();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                conn.Close();
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

`Debug.WriteLine` outputs null

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your cmd.ExecuteNonQuery is not correct you are doing a `Select` not an `UPDATE or INSERT` look up how to use the following 
`SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();` also `DEBUG` the code and re-evaluate your logic and what is this `strTransactionID`

Comment: @DJKRAZE edited Q to show full code. `strTransactionID` is just a string I am using.

Comment: You should also get rid of that try/catch block. All it does is mess up your stack trace.

Comment: In addition, your `OracleConnection` and `OracleCommand` should be in `using` blocks: `using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstring)){
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand()){

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open(); ... return true/false}}

Answer (score 0):

Try placing closing your connection `conn.Close();`  after `Debug.WriteLine` has been completed.

Comment: should wrap that code around a `using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(constring))` as well as the same for the `using(OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())` this way it's auto disposed and no need to explicitly call connection.Close